# Scrape website work during debugging only

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have the following code that takes some numbers and search for them and return a name related to that number

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Const sURL As String = "http://portal.acs.moi.gov.kw/wps/portal/!ut/p/c1/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3jHEEf3EENTIwMLD1dLA88Qv2AzMzM3IwMDU6B8JJK8v3-AmYGRr7G3qYmvhwEQENAdDrIPv36QvAEO4Gig7-eRn5uqH6kfZY7THncz_cic1PTE5Er9gtwIgyyTUEUANhX2ig!!/dl2/d1/L0lJSklna21DU1EhIS9JRGpBQU15QUJFUkNKRXFnL1lGTkExTkk1MC01Rjg5dyEvN19BVEFHVDE1MjA4SEU5MElUTlM2NjZGMjBHNi86bF9fXzQ1LzE5MTU4MzUzNTk!/?"

Sub Test()
    Dim eleSearch As Selenium.WebElement, m As Long, lr As Long, r As Long, cnt As Long
    lr = shSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    m = shSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With bot
        '.AddArgument "--headless"
        .Get sURL
        .SwitchToAlert.Accept
        For r = m To lr
            'If r Mod 10 = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.StatusBar = "Civil ID: " & shSheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value & " ------- Row " & r
STARTPOINT:
            With .FindElementByName("numberValue")
                .Clear: .SendKeys shSheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
            End With
            .FindElementByName("search").Click
            
            shSheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value = Trim(.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").Text)
            
            Dim eleNewSearch As Selenium.WebElement
            Set eleNewSearch = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set eleNewSearch = .FindElementById("openNewSearch")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not eleNewSearch Is Nothing Then
                .FindElementById("openNewSearch").Click
                .Wait 2000
                cnt = 0
            Else
                .FindElementByName("showViolations").Click
                .Wait 2000
                .SwitchToAlert.Accept
                If cnt = 5 Then
                    cnt = 0
                    GoTo NXT
                Else
                    GoTo STARTPOINT
                End If
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
            .Wait 1000
            .SwitchToAlert.Accept
NXT:
        Next r
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = Empty
    MsgBox "Done...", 64, "YasserKhalil"
End Sub
```

When using F8 key, everything is OK and working well, but when run the code to do the task, it works partially and it shows me error page .. Any ideas?
Some numbers to test on `284083101217` `283042604438` `292082601615`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're clicking too fast after entering the number. Try a small wait time between entering & clicking:

```vb
With .FindElementByName("numberValue")
    .Clear: .SendKeys shSheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
End With
.Wait 2000
.FindElementByName("search").Click
```

Might be some kind of DDoS defence on the website?

Comment: It seems that worked partially but the problem is still there.

Comment: By error, do you mean the "لقد تعذرت العملية يرجى المحاولة مرة أخرى بعد قليل - Unprocessd request please try again later." phrase?

Comment: Yes, this means the website doesn't respond properly. Any luck with python packages?

Comment: I suppose I can look into Python, though how about we try `.Wait 2000` instead? I wonder if it has to do with your internet connection: The button itself is an image, so you might need to wait for this image to load.

Comment: In fact, I tried python but with no great success. I need python but I don't want to use selenium.